# What does (extra requests) mean in Parse.com services?

Tags: parse-platform, notifications, push-notification, cloud, push

In Parse's pricing FAQ it is mentioned that "If your app hits its request limit, your extra requests will begin to fail with error code 155 (RequestLimitExceeded)".

What does (extra requests) mean?

Are they the requests made within the same minute? day? month? or all other requests made until the request limit is increased?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Parse.com FAQs](https://parse.com/plans/faq):

> The request limit is calculated on a per-minute basis. For example, if
>   an app is set to 30 requests/second, your app will hit its request
>   limit once it makes more than 1,800 requests over a 60 second period.
>   If your app hits its request limit, your extra requests will begin to
>   fail with error code 155 (RequestLimitExceeded). To prevent the
>   requests from failing you should adjust the request limit slider for
>   the relevant app on the Account Overview page. Please note that you
>   can see your actual requests/second on the Performance Analytics tab.

Your plan supports a certain number of requests per second. *Extra requests* are all requests that are started after the limit defined by your plan has already been reached. As outlined above, it is calculated on a per-minute basis: if more than `60 * your rate per second` requests are made with your API key per minute, some of them will be *extra requests* and fail.

The FAQ entry actually contains an example: If your plan allows for 30 requests to be made per second, every minute `60 * 30 = 1800` requests are allowed. After the minute has passed, the counter will be reset.

Comment: So if my limit is 30 req/s and 1800 requests are made in a certain minute, any other requests (within the same minute) will fail, and a new 1800 allowed requests will be counted the next minute?